# meaning of 'set back the cause'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> When the Uber self-driving car ran over that poor woman in Phoenix,
> the news coverage focused on how it would set back the cause of
> self-driving cars.

In this sentence, what does 'set back the cause' mean?

Answer (score 4):

The [Cambdrige Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cause) lists two meanings of cause: in this sentence, it's the second meaning:

> a socially valuable principle that is strongly supported by some people

**[set back](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/set-sth-sb-back?q=set%20back)** is defined as

> to delay an event, process, or person

In this sentence,  **set back the cause** means to delay the progress toward widespread adoption of self-driving cars- something that many people feel is socially valuable.